# How can I union random selected rows in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, session, union

Now I use this code:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "(SELECT * FROM movies WHERE
    MATCH(title) AGAINST('".$_SESSION['mtitle']."' WITH QUERY EXPANSION) AND
    id NOT LIKE '".$_SESSION['mid']."')
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM movies WHERE category LIKE '%".$cat."%' AND
     id NOT LIKE '".$_SESSION['mid']."' ORDER BY RAND()) LIMIT 5");
```

I would like to list 5 similar movies. When there is 5 or more matches in the first part, it works good. But if isn't, the second selection isn't random, it writes always the same movies in the same sequence.

For example: If I search for Jumanji, the first suggestion is Jumanji, the second is Jumanji: Welcome to the Jungle. But the last 3 is always the same movie.

Answer (score 1):

Group By think be your answer to remove any duplicate values.

```
 `GROUP BY mtitle`

"(SELECT mtitle FROM movies WHERE
MATCH(title) AGAINST('".$_SESSION['mtitle']."' WITH QUERY EXPANSION) AND
id NOT LIKE '".$_SESSION['mid']."')
UNION
(SELECT mtitle FROM movies WHERE category LIKE '%".$cat."%' AND
 id NOT LIKE '".$_SESSION['mid']."') GROUP BY mtitle ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5"
```

Comment: should be `title`

Comment: would not putting LIMIT 5 inside each one of the SELECT queries optimize it further ? So that individual queries are not getting all the data at first, and then grouping on them ?